# How to write a query to fetch recent records from database table

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a table i.e., `table_1` which has different fields. I want to write a `query` to fetch the latest records from column `part_name1` with `issue_priority` based on `time`. Column `part_name1` may contain same record with different priorities like `p1`, `p2` or `p3`. Here I have taken less number of records but if I have n number of records how to fetch the latest among the inserted records.

Just an example is given here. Please check out the given image link

```
**part_name1**      **issue_priority**    **time1**

    blower              p1                 03:15:00
    reverse             p2                 03:16:18
    blower              p2                 04:11:30
    reverse             p3                 04:44:05
```

**Output:** From the above table i want the output to be as mentioned below

```
blower       p2
reverse      p3
```

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGnkV.png)

Comment: select col1,col2 from table_name order by time(col3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to query the latest time for each part_name1. This gives you the maximum time values.

```
SELECT part_name1, max(time1) as maxtime1
FROM table_1
GROUP BY part_name1;
```

If you also need the other data in the table (e.g. issue_priority), you should use the above as a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT part_name1, max(time1) as maxtime1
    FROM table_1
    GROUP BY part_name1 ) s1
ON (t1.part_name1  = s1.part_name1 AND t1.time1 = s1.maxtime1);
```

This will return you the latest row for each part_name1. You can add further `LIMIT` clause, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works fine while fetching old records.

Answer (score 1):

Use max(time1) instead of min(time1) to fetch latest inserted records.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN (
SELECT part_name1, max(time1) as maxtime1
FROM table_1 
GROUP BY part_name1 ) s1
ON (t1.part_name1  = s1.part_name1 AND t1.time1 = s1.maxtime1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use ORDER BY :

```
SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY time1 DESC LIMIT 2;
```

In your case, fields is part_name1, table is the name of your table and LIMIT 2 is because you want exactly the last 2 records ( can be set to any number ).

Comment: here time is not in timestamp format so you have to convert time column to timestamp while fetching data, this might be proper way ! what do you think?

Comment: @alexandru.tapirdea Thank you for your response. Is there any other way without using limit. Because sometimes I may not be knowing how many records are there. Please check out the given image link.

Comment: @AamnaD the simple way is to remove LIMIT 2. This means you will always receive all event, ordered by time1. After that, you can decide on backend how many of them you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT part_name1, issue_priority
FROM table_1
ORDER BY time1 DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Limit 2 will give you the two most recent records. If you remove the LIMIT then you will get all records ordered by time1 from newest to oldest.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html